# hover using jquery remove current tab

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I have a menu and when I  hover on over tabs beneath it I wanted to remove the "current" class while hovering the other tab/s. For now the situation is I need to hover the "current" tab in order for the current class to be removed. What I wanted, when I hover directly on the next tab/s the "current" class will automatically remove. Please see my demo link.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/58Lfg9ee/1/)

I have also tried this code:

```js
$('.left-menu >li').on('mouseover', '>a', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('on');
}).on('mouseleave', '>a', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('on');
});
```

```css
.left-menu {
  width: 180px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.left-menu li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 44px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  background: #fff;
}
.left-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #313131;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.left-menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.left-menu li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.left-menu li.current {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.left-menu li.current a {
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
}
.left-menu li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.left-menu li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li><a href="#">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">tab3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

by removing the "current" class but it is necessary to  be there. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.siblings()` method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in order to also remove the class from the sibling elements. Additionally, the [`.addBack()` method](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) is used to add back the current element as well.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sgmc6aLd/)

```
$('.left-menu >li').on('mouseover', '>a', function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().addBack().removeClass('current');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. this is the answer I am looking.